# Bower installs but gives error on every command

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, bower

I've installed bower via npm `npm install -g bower`, i get no problems. But when i want to run bower, even just `bower` or `bower -help` i get the following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^ 
Error: Cannot find module './parser'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/handlebars/lib/handlebars/compiler/base.js:1:80)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

cannot seem to find anyone else with this problem online.

Comment: +1 I'm getting errors on every command except `Cannot find module 'touch'`

Comment: I tried installing Bower again recently and now it works for me. Nothing really i changed on my system; so i guess it was a broken build for me. Yay bower!